# Laravel PayPal Error : The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using `srmklive/laravel-paypal` package for my `laravel` shopping cart. I want to add shipping cost to the sub total.But when I try to execute paypal `setExpressCheckout` with checkout data, I got `paypal api` error called **"The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts"**.

Here is my `PaypalController`

```
    public function getExpressCheckout($id,$data,$total){
            $orderData = json_decode($data,true);
            $checkoutData = [
                'items' => $orderData,
                'return_url' => route('paypal.success', $id),
                'cancel_url' => route('paypal.cancel'),
                'invoice_id' => uniqid(),
                'invoice_description' => " Order Description ",    
            ];

            $sub_total = 0;
            foreach ($orderData as $item) {
                $sub_total += $item['price'] * $item['qty'];
            }
            $checkoutData['shipping'] = 5; //example
            $checkoutData['sub_total'] = $sub_total;
            $checkoutData['total'] = $sub_total+ $checkoutData['shipping'];
            //$checkoutData['shipping_discount'] = round((10 / 100) * $sub_total, 2);
            

            $provider = new ExpressCheckout();

            $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($checkoutData);
            dd($response, $orderData);
        // return redirect($response['paypal_link']);

            return response()->json(['message' => 'PayPal Link', 'link' => $response['paypal_link']], 200);

        }
```

OrderItems array

```
array:3 [
        0 => array:3 [
            "name" => "sssss"
            "price" => 1250
            "qty" => "1"
        ]
        1 => array:3 [
            "name" => "Upuli Bhagyadf  cgfd d"
            "price" => 1062.5
            "qty" => "1"
        ]
        2 => array:3 [
            "name" => "sssss  dfd"
            "price" => 1100
            "qty" => "1"
        ]
    ]
```

I got below error

```
array:10 [
            "TIMESTAMP" => "2020-10-05T09:30:49Z"
            "CORRELATIONID" => "1c41cbb7e7447"
            "ACK" => "Failure"
            "VERSION" => "123"
            "BUILD" => "54950761"
            "L_ERRORCODE0" => "10413"
            "L_SHORTMESSAGE0" => "Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details."
            "L_LONGMESSAGE0" => "The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts."
            "L_SEVERITYCODE0" => "Error"
            "paypal_link" => null
        ]
```

`$checkoutData['shipping'] = 0;` or `not exist` There is no error, Its working fine. So How I can add addional shipping cost to `sub_total`

Comment: First of all try to put some hard-coded data and check the response so that you can make sure the issue is in amount figures only

Comment: `$checkoutData['shipping'] = 0;`  or not exist There is no error, Its working fine. So How I can add addional shipping cost to `sub_total`.

Comment: Hi Wesly. No. Thats not.

Comment: In that case, please show the content of `$orderData`

Comment: Hi Wesly,I updated question with `$orderData`